# Postgres - Golang Error: pq: Users does not exists

Tags: postgresql, go

I'm trying to connect Golang to a Postgres DB, it is in Gcloud and I already allowed the network IP. I'm trying to access the User DB and then the User table inside the public schema, this is the database structure:

[image]

I am getting this error: `pq: database "Users" does not exist`

I'll add the code:

```
package ports

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func OpenConnection(dbName string) (*sql.DB, error) {
    connStr := "<addr>" + dbName
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db, err
}

func GetUsers(ctx *fiber.Ctx) error {
    db, dbErr := OpenConnection("Users")

    if dbErr != nil {
        log.Fatalln(dbErr)
    }

    defer db.Close()
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM Users")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        ctx.JSON("An error ocurred")
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    return ctx.Render("/users", fiber.Map{
        "Users": rows,
    })
}
```

Comment: Did you try connecting through your terminal with the `psql` tool and using the same connection string as the value of the `connStr` variable in your Go code?

Comment: Note that you should not open/close the `sql.DB` instance per every request. That is, you should not be calling `sql.Open` (directly or indirectly) inside your fiber handlers. If you do that your program will be very slow.

Comment: Note also that the result of `db.Query` is of type `*sql.Rows` and this type is not intended to be sent to clients as JSON. You need to first scan the contents of the `rows` into a slice of objects (maps, or structs with exported fields) and then send that slice as the `"Users": ...` element of the `fieber.Map{ ... }`.

Comment: Are you certain you are connecting to the correct server? I ask because this is en error given by the postgres database server so you have reached a server and it has accepted your credentials as those are checked first.

Comment: Yes, I actually already have a hasura that is working and I just reused the url that's already there. So I am positive the URL is correct, but I'm fuzzy about is the way database sql is expecting the query, because the url will go as far as the actual db, inside that db there is a public schema with 2 tables inside. I want to access those two tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just fixed it and it was a combination of two things:

1. I wasn't properly combining the strings, when I hardcoded it I got rid of the db error.
2. After that I encountered an error where it would say the table doesn't exists, the issue is I was sending an unquote table name and I needed it to be case sensitive so I had to wrap the name between quotes to make it work. Like so

```
package ports

import (
    "database/sql"
    "log"

    "github.com/gofiber/fiber/v2"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)

func OpenConnection() (*sql.DB, error) {
    connStr := "<connStr>/users"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    return db, err
}

func GetUsers(ctx *fiber.Ctx, db *sql.DB) error {

    defer db.Close()
    rows, err := db.Query(`SELECT * FROM "Users"`)

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalln(err)
        ctx.JSON("An error ocurred")
    }

    defer rows.Close()

    return ctx.Render("/users", fiber.Map{
        "Users": rows,
    })
}
```

Comment: *"the library sends the name in lowercase"* -- That's not a "library" thing. That's how [PostgreSQL](https://postgresql.org/docs/14/interactive/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS) works: *"Quoting an identifier also makes it case-sensitive, whereas **unquoted names are always folded to lower case**."*

Comment: Thanks so much for the correction! I'll edit the answer.